# PySpark SQL TRY_CAST?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have data in a Dataframe, all columns as strings. Now, some of the data in a column is numeric so I could cast to float. Other rows actually contain strings which I do not want to cast.

So I was looking for something like a try_cast, and already tried building something on `.when().otherwise()` but didn't succeed so far.

```
casted = data.select(when(col("Value").cast("float").isNotNull(), col("Value").cast("float")).otherwise(col("Value")))
```

This does not work, it will never cast in the end.

Is something like this generally possible (in a performant manner without UDFs etc)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have a column with two types in spark: either float or string. That's why your column has always `string` type (because it can contain both: strings and floats).

What your code does, is: if the number in `Value` column doesn't fit into float, it will be casted to float, and then to string (try with >6 decimal places). As far as I know TRY_CAST converts to value or null (at least in SQL Server), so this is exactly what spark's `cast` does.

Comment: I don't understand that sentence "if the number in `Value` column doesn't fit into float, it will be casted to float, and then to string (try with >6 decimal places)"
But I guess your general point is valid here: A column cannot contain different types

Comment: Try the experiment with dataframe containing string "3.111111111111" in column `Value`. Your code should cast it to string "3.11111" due to string->float->string conversion.